# Disable sibling div when one of the div is clicked and get the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I click on one of the DIV it will find the check-box inside the DIV and "Check" it. So the other DIV will hide. 
I am facing problem on How do I disable other DIV When the time it is hiding itself or else I can click other DIV and broke the initial idea by only left the DIV that is clicked.

2)How do I get the value of the checked div ?

3)How do I detect if no check-box were selected ??

TQ

```
 <div id="answer">
    <h3>A</h3>
    <p id="result">Tick the correct answer</p>
    <div id="a1">A. <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="ans" ></input></div>
    <div id="a2">B. <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="ans"></input></div>
    <div id="a3">C. <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="ans"></input></div>
    <div id="a4">D. <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="ans"></input></div>
    </div>

    <button id="checkbtn">Check Answer</button>


var btncounter = 0;
$("#checkbtn").hide();
$("#answer > div").click(function (e) {
e.stopPropagation();
    var status = $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop('checked'); 
    $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", !status);
    $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle(!status);
    btncounter++;
    if(btncounter%2 == 1)
    $("#checkbtn").show();
    else
    $("#checkbtn").hide();
});
```

Comment: you want to allow the user to select only one checkbox is that right?

Comment: yeap , after selected i get the value. If deselect the value is 0;

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4T6uR/3/

Comment: after user selected the answer and check if it is right or not.
1)when clicked the button will come out
2)when clicked will get the value
3)if no checkbox no button

Comment: `input` tags are selfclosing tags so you don't close them with `</input>`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$("#checkbtn").hide();
$("#answer > div").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").trigger("click");

});
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {

    $(this).parent().siblings('div').slideToggle();
    $("#checkbtn").toggle();

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X2SPM/18/)

**Edit**

```
    var btncounter = 0;
$("#checkbtn").hide();
$("#answer > div").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled")) {
        $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").trigger("click");
    }
});
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").not(this).attr("disabled", true);
    $(this).parent().siblings('div').stop().slideToggle("slow", function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").not(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $("#checkbtn").toggle();

    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#checkbtn").click(function(){
   alert($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent().text());
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/X2SPM/24/)

Comment: try clicking the div very fast , it will check the other box aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#checkbtn").hide();

var $checks = $("#answer > div input:checkbox").change(function (e) {
    $divs.stop(true);

    var $div = $(this).parent();
    var $sibs = $divs.not($div)[this.checked ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
    $div.slideDown();

    $sibs.find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $("#checkbtn").toggle($checks.filter(':checked').length > 0);
})

var $divs = $("#answer > div").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('input')) {
        $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", function (i, checked) {
            return !checked;
        }).change();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4T6uR/)